# need a regex for password validation that allows all special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, passwords

The password requirements are:

- at least two letters
- at least two numbers
- at least one special character (any special character)
- at least 8 characters

This one is close but isn't working:
`/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\W]).{8,}$/`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: using a regex for this

Comment: did you want the OR of above?

Comment: What's the difference between letters and characters?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, a letter is a-z. A character is anything, including digits, punctuation and other special characters.

Comment: does the letter wouldn't mean a capital `A-Z`?

Answer (score 4):

This regex meets your requirements:

```
/^(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2})(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){2})(?=.*[!-\/:-@\[-`{-~]).{8,}$/i
```

Play with [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/jX4lY4) to see what matches and doesn't match.

**Explanation**

- This is a classic password validation technique with lookarounds as explained in [this article](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)
- The `i` flag at the end makes it case-insensitive so we don't have to say `a-zA-Z`
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The first lookahead `(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2})` asserts that what follows at this position (the beginning of the string) is any characters that are not a letter, followed by one letter... twice, ensuring there are at least two letters
- The second lookahead `(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){2})` asserts that  what follows at this position (still the beginning of the string) is any characters that are not a digit, followed by one digit... twice, ensuring there are at least two letters
- The third lookahead `(?=.*[!-\/:-@\[-`{-~])` asserts that  what follows at this position (still the beginning of the string) is any characters, followed by one special character
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

**Note about special characters**

The regex `[!-\/:-@\[-`{-~]` specifically picks out all printable chars that are neither digits nor letters from [the ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). If this includes chars you don't want, make it more restrictive.

Comment: Hmmm.  I don't use it, but I don't see in the documentation where javascript supports mode modifiers

Comment: @RonRosenfeld It works. JS doesn't support modifiers inline, such as `(?i)`, which is why I put it after the pattern, in the `/i`

Answer (score 2):

A regex is probably inappropriate for this; it's hard to glance at the regex you've got and immediately have any idea what the requirements are, let alone how to modify them.  You might want to just count the number of characters in each group directly, then check that those counts all pass the appropriate threshold.

That said: consider that this would enforce really awkward passwords, yet disallow [xkcd-style passwords](http://xkcd.com/936/).  I strongly encourage you to take a more heuristic approach, where a longer password loosens the other restrictions.  There are other considerations to enforcing a strong password, too, like similarity to dictionary words and number of *unique* characters.

Honestly you might be best off just requiring passphrases  :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

```
/^(?=.*\d.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\W]).{8,}$/
```

Your regex was missing the **2** digits and **2** letters requirements.

Comment: FYI apart from all the backtracking, that regex doesn't validate `abcd_1234`, which is a valid password. :)

Comment: That's because `_` is considered a word character in \w. One option is to add it in the class, the other is to use `[^A-Za-z0-9]`

Comment: Yes, I know why... I'm just pointing the problem out.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
/^(?=.{2,}\d)(?=.{2,}[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\W]).{8,}$/
```

It should meet your requirement.

Comment: Nope. This says there should be 1 digit somewhere from the 3rd position, 1 letter somewhere from the 3rd position, a special character, at least 8 characters.

Comment: Fails on:  12aaaaaaa? and  aa1234567?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you consider to be a "special character".  If a special character is anything that is not a digit or a letter, and if Spaces are not allowed in the password, then:

```
^(?=(?:\S*\d){2})(?=(?:\S*[A-Za-z]){2})(?=\S*[^A-Za-z0-9])\S{8,}
```

or, with the "escapes":

```
"^(?=(?:\\S*\\d){2})(?=(?:\\S*[A-Za-z]){2})(?=\\S*[^A-Za-z0-9])\\S{8,}"
```

If you choose to allow spaces, replace \S with a dot .

If you want to define "special characters" as only including certain characters, or as excluding other characters in addition to letters and digits, edit the character class in the final lookahead.